# how to convert time(mktime) to date(mm/dd/yyyy) in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date, mktime

ok i have a birthday form that will save as time using mktime, so when it is saved in mysql, it will show something like 634608000..  how can i convert it to mm/dd/yyyy format so that when it is displayed in html it will be readable..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
 date('m/d/Y',$time)
```

Comment: does this return hh:mm:ss also?

Comment: No, but if you look at the options for date function, you can add that on as well.